# SQL Server Distributed Transactions: xp_sqljdbc_xa_commit vs xp_sqljdbc_xa_end

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, distributed-transactions

In SQL Server 2019, can anyone definitively tell me the functional difference between xp_sqljdbc_xa_commit & xp_sqljdbc_xa_end?

My guess is that commit is attempting to commit the transaction (thank you Mr. Obvious ;-) ) and end is telling DTC "hey, all done here. Please clean up."

But, the code appears to live in SQLJDBC_XA.dll (as extended sp) so I can't view it, and I can't find a good reference to confirm my assumptions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server JDBC Driver's source code on GitHub is a great place to track this down.

```
@Override
public void end(Xid xid, int flags) throws XAException {
    // Called by the transaction mgr after the app closes the connection it was given from this physical
    // connection
    /*
     * Ends the work performed on behalf of a transaction branch. The resource manager disassociates the XA resource
     * from the transaction branch specified and let the transaction be completed. If TMSUSPEND is specified in
     * flags, the transaction branch is temporarily suspended in incomplete state. The transaction context is in
     * suspened state and must be resumed via start with TMRESUME specified. If TMFAIL is specified, the portion of
     * work has failed. The resource manager may mark the transaction as rollback-only. If TMSUCCESS is specified,
     * the portion of work has completed successfully.
     */
    DTC_XA_Interface(XA_END, xid, flags | tightlyCoupled);
}
```

[src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerXAResource.java](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/145d0b606f2f015036f39c6af87724a40ccf641f/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerXAResource.java)

So it's used by SQL Server's implementation of the [XAResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/transaction/xa/XAResource.html) interface.

For background see [How It Works: SQL Server DTC (MSDTC and XA Transactions)](https://bobsql.com/how-it-works-sql-server-dtc-msdtc-and-xa-transactions/)